# I use to_gbq on pandas for updating Google BigQuery and get GenericGBQException

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

While trying to use **to_gbq** for updating Google BigQuery table, I get a response of:

```
GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
```

My code:

```
gbq.to_gbq(mini_df,'Name-of-Table','Project-id',chunksize=10000,reauth=False,if_exists='append',private_key=None)
```

and my dataframe of mini_df looks like:

```
date    request_number  name    feature_name    value_name  value
2018-01-10  1   1   "a" "b" 0.309457
2018-01-10  1   1   "c" "d" 0.273748
```

While I'm running the **to_gbq**, and there's no table on the BigQuery, I can see that the table is created with the next schema:

date    STRING  NULLABLE
request_number  STRING  NULLABLE
name    STRING  NULLABLE
feature_name    STRING  NULLABLE
value_name  STRING  NULLABLE
value   FLOAT   NULLABLE

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

P.S, rest of the exception:

```
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize)
    589                         destination_table,
--> 590                         job_config=job_config).result()
    591                 except self.http_error as ex:

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in result(self, timeout)
    527         # TODO: modify PollingFuture so it can pass a retry argument to done().
--> 528         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
    529 

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout)
    110             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 111             raise self._exception
    112 

BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GenericGBQException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-195df93249b6> in <module>()
----> 1 gbq.to_gbq(mini_df,'Name-of-Table','Project-id',chunksize=10000,reauth=False,if_exists='append',private_key=None)

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key)
    106                       chunksize=chunksize,
    107                       verbose=verbose, reauth=reauth,
--> 108                       if_exists=if_exists, private_key=private_key)

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key, auth_local_webserver)
    987         table.create(table_id, table_schema)
    988 
--> 989     connector.load_data(dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize)
    990 
    991 

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize)
    590                         job_config=job_config).result()
    591                 except self.http_error as ex:
--> 592                     self.process_http_error(ex)
    593 
    594                 rows = []

~/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in process_http_error(ex)
    454         # <https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors>`__
    455 
--> 456         raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
    457 
    458     def run_query(self, query, **kwargs):

GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the very same problem.

In my case it depended on the data type `object` of the Data Frame.

I've had three columns `externalId`, `mappingId`, `info`. For none of those fields I set a data type and let pandas do it's magic.

It decided to set all three column data types to `object`. Problem is, internally the `to_gbq` component uses the `to_json` component. For some reason or another this output omits the quotes around the data field if the type of the field is `object` but holds only numerical values.

So Google Big Query needed this

```
{"externalId": "12345", "mappingId":"abc123", "info":"blerb"}
```

but got this:

```
{"externalId": 12345, "mappingId":"abc123", "info":"blerb"}
```

And because the mapping of the field was `STRING` in Google Big Query, the import process failed.

Two solutions came up.

**Solution 1 - Change the data type of the column**

A simple type conversion helped with this issue. I also had to change the data type in Big Query to `INTEGER`.

```
df['externalId'] = df['externalId'].astype('int')
```

If this is the case, Big Query can consume fields without quotes as the JSON standard says.

**Solution 2 - Make sure the string field is a string**

Again, this is setting the data type. But since we set it explicitly to `String`, the export with `to_json` prints out a quoted field and everything worked fine.

```
df['externalId'] = df['externalId'].astype('str')
```

Comment: Do you know if this version of making the string field a string, ````df['a'] = df['a'].astype('|S')```` will work as well?